# Iterate over jq loop: assign key if value.subvalue matches condition

Tags: json, bash, iteration, jq

I'm trying to perform some work on keys whose value matches a certain condition. First, the json I'm working with looks similar to this when I execute a CLI tool in linux:

```
$ ./sacli ClusterQuery

  "i-aaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb": {
    "sacli_ip": "10.0.52.37",
    "sacli_listen_ip": "10.0.52.37",
    "sacli_port": "945"
  },
  "i-ccccccccddddddddd": {
    "sacli_ip": "10.0.48.68",
    "sacli_listen_ip": "10.0.48.68",
    "sacli_port": "945"
  }
```

I would ideally like to loop through these entries, do a check and then perform operations based on the check. So conceptually:

```
for i in $(./sacli ClusterQuery | jq -r '<some syntax to get each key, value>'); do
  node_id=key
  ip=value.sacli_ip

  ping -c 1 -W 1 $ip
  ping_result=$?

  if [[ $ping_result -eq 1 ]]; then #ping has failed
     ./remove $node_id
  fi
done
```

Comment: Please fix the sample JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd avoid your `for` loop in favor of piping to `while`, like this:

```
./sacli ClusterQuery | jq -rc '
    keys_unsorted[] as $k | $k, .[$k].sacli_ip' |
  while read -r node_id ; do
    read -r ip   
    ping -c 1 -W 1 "$ip"
    ping_result=$?
    if [[ $ping_result -eq 1 ]]; then #ping has failed
      echo ./remove "$node_id"
    fi
  done
```

This assumes the keys and sacli_ip values don't have embedded newlines.

You can of course easily add the appropriate `select` filter(s) inside the jq program.

The `-c` is there for safety.